# Данные не возвращаются от сервера JSONP

Tags: php, javascript

Помогите получить ответ от сервера.
Есть функция выполнения запросов в формате JSONP c помощью тега script

```js
function call(a) {
  alert(a);
}
function getJSONP(url, callback) {
    // Create a unique callback name just for this request
    var cbnum = "cb" + getJSONP.counter++; // Increment counter each time
    var cbname = "getJSONP." + cbnum;      // As a property of this function
    if (url.indexOf("?") === -1)   // URL doesn't already have a query section
        url += "?jsonp=" + cbname; // add parameter as the query section
    else                           // Otherwise, 
        url += "&jsonp=" + cbname; // add it as a new parameter.

   
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    getJSONP[cbnum] = function(response) {
        try {
            callback(response); // Handle the response data
        }
        finally {               // Even if callback or response threw an error
            delete getJSONP[cbnum];                // Delete this function
            script.parentNode.removeChild(script); // Remove script
        }
    };

   
    script.src = url;                  // Set script url
    document.body.appendChild(script); // Add it to the document
}

getJSONP.counter = 0;  // A counter we use to create unique callback names


getJSONP( "ph.php", call);
getJSONP( "http://my/ph.php", call);
```

А вот сам ph.php от куда в качестве ответа должны приходит данные

```js
<?php
 $seq = array("foo", "bar", "baz", "blong");
 $json = json_encode($seq);
 echo $json
```

Но браузер выводит ошибки:
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Подробнее]  ph.php:1
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Подробнее]

Comment: Почему никто никогда не пишет сам текст ошибки? Это информация несущественна? >_<

Comment: Суть в том что функция которая должна быть вызвана сценарием не вызывается.
Ошибки:
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Подробнее]  ph.php:1

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'[Подробнее]

Comment: точку с запятой поставь после  `echo $json` ...................`Суть в том что функция которая должна быть вызвана сценарием не вызывается.` - логично. т.к. ошика вылазит - сценарий стопорится и всё остальное не выполняется

Comment: Да, теперь ошибок нет. Но скритп не выполняется и не принимает ответ, так так script.parentNode.removeChild(script); по сценарию в .js должен выполняться и удаляться

Comment: судя по коду - не должен. ибо `getJSONP[cbnum]` ни разу не вызывается...... а то, что внутри функции `getJSONP`  написано  `getJSONP[cbnum]` - вообще молчу

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp

Comment: Внутри функции getJSONP написано getJSONP[cbnum] Так это замыкание... getJSONP[cbnum] должна по логике вызываться

Comment: а вы попробуйте ваш пхп скрипт открыть в браузере. если выдаёт нужные данные - ок, если нет -  проблема на сервере. и мне кажется ваш пхп просто не интерпретирует, а уходит с сервера как есть

Comment: `так это замыкание` ..... замыкание - это не значит объявил и оно само когда-то как-то вызовется.

Comment: Оно вызовется сразу же, после добавления этого  document.body.appendChild(script); тега в документ. Это называется "запрос в формате JSONP с помощью элемента <sctipt>" Стратегия: вызывается функция getJSONP в которой создаётся тег <script>, который в свою очередь и вызывает функцию getJSONP[cbnum], а после вызова её удаляет

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS нет, вы не понимаете. вы никогда не вызываете `getJSONP[cbnum]`... это просто function expresion, который чтобы вызывать - надо писать `getJSONP[cbnum]()` ...... а этого **нет**.... Написал ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. По поводу ошибки синтаксиса я уже писал в комментариях. Повторю:

   после `echo $json` надо поставить точку с запятой
2. `jsonp` предполагает, что будет возвращаться не просто `json`, а обернутый в , так сказать, "доверяющую" функцию. Вы же не просто так задаете идентификатор для `callback`, а говорите, что вот именно этому запросу я буду доверять и исполню его как только он придет. В итоге, нужно на сервере писать:

   ```
   // header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); // пока не обязательно, но возможно понадобится

   $seq = array("foo", "bar", "baz", "blong");
   $json = json_encode($seq);

   // вот ключевая строка - мы берем GET параметр, достаем из него идентификатор
   // callback'а и возвращаем ответ с "вызовом" этого самого колбэка, в который
   // и передаем ответ. В итоге на клиенте сможет отработать
   // функция вот таким образом  --->  getJSONP[cbnum]()  <---        
   echo $_GET['jsonp'].'('.$json.')';

   exit();
   ```

   В данном случае ответ будет иметь вид: `getJSONP.cb0(["foo","bar","baz","blong"])`

Comment: Да вот спасибо, надо было правильно вопрос задать, что не могу отправить ответ на сервере

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS  кстати, думаю, наверное вместо имени `getJSONP` стоит посылать более понятное `callback` или `CallbackRegistry` как в ссылке, что я приводи в комментарии. и `cb0` сделать побольше и разнообразнее. Опять же можно подсмотреть на https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-jsonp

Comment: И на последок, а почему должны быть всегда разные имена функции?

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS ну например если делаются несколько разных асинхронных запросов к разным адресам... да и просто чтоб не подделать